# Generating new Column from existing two Columns DATA

Tags: python, matlab, python-2.7, matlab-deployment

I want a Matlab or Python code to Compare two columns data i-e **Column A** and **Column B** and on the basis of comparison  a new column should generate which is **Column C**.

As an Example:

[image]

The comparison be like in the above example: if **2 interact with 4** , **4 interacts with 8** and **2 interacts with 8** so the new **Column C** must have only one value and the value can be  **2 ,4 or 5** to complete the set. Following three possibilites can be made from the above values.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give the desired column C in the example?

Comment: The desired column C has only one value i-e 5.

Comment: Ok. I still can't catch the "comparison" method... Maybe try to explain more about it..?

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Please show us a sample of column C that you expect.  I actually don't quite understand what it is you want.

Comment: And as you described it, shouldn't the the result be `[3, 4, 5; 3, 4, 1; 7, 3, 4; 7, 3, 2; 7 , 3, 5]` ?  And what version of matlab do you have?

Comment: Shouldn't the one-before-last row also have a 5?  There is 7 -- 3 (in the one-before-last of A and B) and then there is 3 -- 5 in the last row, so we have 7 -- 3 -- 5.  So C would be: [ 0 5 ... (zeros) ... 5 0 ].  Do you always "_compare_" including only the very next row?

Comment: @zdim No it couldn't be necessary to compare it with the very next row. Maybe the association is after 3 or 4 rows or it can be in very next row.

Comment: @Adiel I edit the question. I think it would be easy to solve now.

Comment: I thought you were asking for essentially a SQL type innerjoin, but I'm entirely confused now. Why not [4, 2, 8] or [8, 2, 4]? What is the S column? What does "interact" mean? I'm completely lost.